# Frontend and backend in one single docker container. Which IP address to use?

Tags: django, docker, networking

I have a docker container running a frontend (react) on port 3000 and a backend (django) on port 8000. From inside the container I can run

```
wget localhost:8000/
```

and I get back what the server has to give me back. This also works if I forward port 8000 and I call wget from outside the container.

But what about the frontend? Since it resides in the same container of the backend, I suppose it resides in the same localhost, so it should be able to retrieve the information from the backend using

```
wget localhost:8000/
```

But this is not what happens (I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
Is it because when I run the frontend, the request comes actually from the browser on my local machine, which lives outside the container (and also outside the server)?

Or am I getting something wrong and wget localhost:8000/ should work also from my browser?

Comment: How are you actually "running" the frontend?  Is it compiled down to static files, in which case a URL like `http://localhost:8000/static` could retrieve it?  Or are you trying to run a dev server in the same container as the backend, in which case a second container might be simpler and clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frontend is running in your browser and therefore your thought that the request comes from your browser is the correct one. In this case you would have to expose a port for the Django backend so your browser can get to it from the "public" IP space.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like only port 8000 is mapped.

If you start the container make sure to add `-p 3000:3000`